# gem install pg works but bundle install doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-postgresql, pg, libpq

`env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config` works but when I try to run bundle install it throws this error

`Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)`

Comment: not sure how to answer my own question but I'll leave this here to help future people I solved this issue by running env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install

Comment: What environment (OS) are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by running `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" bundle install`